# Adding a value to a 'datetime2' column caused an overflow. EF Core Date Comparison

Tags: datetime, entity-framework-core

Hi have a Entity Called `TableOne` and it has Property as below:

```
[Column(TypeName = "datetime2(7)")]
public DateTime ActualDeliveryDateTime { get; set; }
```

In Select Query, I'm checking this Property against Current DateTime value as below:

```
 var authorisation = _db.TableOne.OrderByDescending(ar => ar.Id).FirstOrDefault(a =>
  .......
    (
       DateTime.UtcNow >= a.ActualDeliveryDateTime.AddHours(-2) &&
       DateTime.UtcNow <= a.ActualDeliveryDateTime.AddHours(4)
    ) 
.......
```

But, I'm getting this error: `Adding a value to a 'datetime2' column caused an overflow`. Please help.

Comment: What values are in the datetime2 column?

Comment: Also, it would be much safer if you created the earliest and latest times you want and compare them directly with the values in the database, rather than adding and subtracting for every single row in your table.

Comment: @DavidG `2021-12-17 13:57:00.8040709`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by reversing the Logic.

```
(
    DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-4) <= a.ActualDeliveryDateTime &&
    DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(2) >= a.ActualDeliveryDateTime
)
```

In this case no need to `AddHours` to SQL Column, instead added to `Current` date.